# Convert ActiveRecord array serialized attribute to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activerecord

I'm working on a Rails 3.2 app that uses [ActiveRecord's serialize method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) to store a model attribute in the form of an array this way:

`serialize :bucket, Array`

I want to remove that serialization and only store a string. The problem is that when I do it I'm left with a string stored this way:

`ruby
[62] pry(main)> bucket.inspect
=> "\"---\\n- something something\\n\""`

How can I clean that string into just `something something` ? I tried using regex but I can't form a proper matcher. This is my closest attempt:

`bucket.scan(/\---\\n- (.*?)\\n/)`

Comment: What is the value of  `bucket` before it is stored?

Comment: @rantingsonrails `['something something']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source of that method, you'll see that since `Array` doesn't respond to both `:load` and `:dump`, it ends up using a `Coders::YAMLColumn` to store the data as a string. So, if you no longer wish to serialize it in this way, you can use that class to `load` the data back out of a string, into an `Array`, and then restructure the array into a string of your choosing. You can also just use `YAML`, since `Coders::YAMLColumn` just seems to wrap that with some type checking:

```
require 'yaml'
# this should be the value of bucket if you don't inspect it
array = YAML.load("---\n- something something\n") 
# => ["something something"]
array.join(' ') # or first or join with whatever else, deal with it how you want
# => "something something"
```